# How to describe object in Mongoose schema to store any property including defined?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How to describe object in Mongoose schema to store any property including defined property that should be indexed?

I have Mongoose schema with structure like this:

```js
{
    a: { type: Object, require: true }
}
```

I don't know all fields in object `a` but I know it contain string `b`, and I should create index at this field.

I can do something like this:

```js
{
    a: {
        b: { type: String, require: true, index: true }
    }
}
```

But in this case other properties of object `a` will be lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define index on schema level:

```
yourSchema.index({ "a.b": 1, type: 1 });
```